How do I enable RTC driver in yocto
I'm trying to enable a RTC driver for DS1337. I specifed a cfg file to contains
CONFIG_CMD_DATE=y
CONFIG_RTC_DS1337=y

When I look at the .config output I see
# CONFIG_RTC_DS1337 is not set
How do I enable the CONFIG_RTC_DS1337 to be enabled?

I believe CONFIG_CMD_DATE is in the u-boot configuration file, are you sure you modified the kernel config?
